# Find and replace word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find and replace word in Javascript, the html structure cannot be change so I have to change using JS only, cant use jQuery, not so good with Javascript though:

**HTML structure is following:**

```
<a id="ys-cc-tablink">
  <em>
     <img src="card.jpg">
     <span>&nbsp;Credit / Debit Card</span>
  </em>
</a>
```

I am trying to replace ***Credit/Debit Cart*** with Title ***Payment*** what I have tried is below and working fine as well:

```
$("#ys-cc-tablink > em > span").each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).text(text.replace(' Credit / Debit Card', 'Payment')); 
});
```

But I need in Javascript instead of jQuery, can somebody please help?

thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
 var str = document.getElementById("demo").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML; 
 var res = str.replace("Credit / Debit Card", "Payment");
 document.getElementById("ys-cc-tablink").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which part did you get stuck on? There are several components here. Have you tried to work through them at all before asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Updated my question with what I have tried so far

Comment: Typo on `getElementById("demo")`?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yes, it was just a typo, worked now. thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all elements using `querySelectorAll` the loop through them and check if the text you want to replace exist then replace it :

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('#ys-cc-tablink span');

for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
    var span_text = spans[i].innerText;

    if(span_text.indexOf('Credit / Debit Card') != -1)
        spans[i].innerText = span_text.replace("Credit / Debit Card", "Payment");
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('#ys-cc-tablink span');

for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
  var span_text = spans[i].innerText;

  if(span_text.indexOf('Credit / Debit Card') != -1)
    spans[i].innerText = span_text.replace("Credit / Debit Card", "Payment");
}
```

```html
<a id="ys-cc-tablink">
  <em>
     <img src="">
     <span>&nbsp;My Credit / Debit Card</span><br>
     <span>&nbsp;test</span><br>
     <span>&nbsp;Credit / Debit Card and some extra text</span>
  </em>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the element reference:

```
var elem = document
  .getElementById("ys-cc-tablink")
  .getElementsByTagName("em")[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
```

Replacement Block of code:

```
elem.innerHTML.replace("Credit / Debit Card", "Payment")
```

```js
var elem = document
  .getElementById("ys-cc-tablink")
  .getElementsByTagName("em")[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace("Credit / Debit Card", "Payment");
```

```html
<a id="ys-cc-tablink">
  <em>
     <img src="card.jpg">
     <span>&nbsp;Credit / Debit Card</span>
  </em>
</a>
```

Comment: @sanjeev Does this help? or we need some improvement here...

Answer (score -1):

I’m guessing your problem has to do with the non-breaking space `&nbsp;` entity. But if you’re replacing the whole text anyway, why don’t you use `$(this).text('Payment')`?

For reference, the NBSP can be represented in JavaScript as `\u00A0`. So you can do `$(this).text(text.replace('\u00A0Credit / Debit Card', 'Payment'));`

Without jQuery, use `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('...', '...');` or `element.textContent = ...`

Comment: I am trying to do it with javascript only, not jQuery

Comment: I’ve edited my answer, please take a look